# When I run nodemon server I get the error "bad auth Authentication failed. [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, port, nodemon

I have been working on a node.js / react app and I uploaded it to heroku. About a month ago it worked  (locally and on heroku). Now it doesn't. I seem to get the same error when I run nodemon server  even when I download old commits of the app (which did work). Terminal does this:

```
TDI-MacBook-Air:udemy-MERN-FromGithub bob$ nodemon server
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server started on Port 5000
bad auth Authentication failed.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**1.** downloaded old an old commit from my githum https://github.com/PaulAyling/COURSE-MernStackFrontToBack

**2.** ran at the terminal: `npm install`

**3.** Ran at terminal `nodemon server` (got the same error as before).

**4.** I tried connecting to the mongo database with postman and got the following error:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/api/posts.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

After reading the error I changed the SSL Certificate verification to off but it did not fix the problem

Theres quite alot of code - not sure what the most usefull files would be - but it did work a month ago.

The full code is here: https://github.com/PaulAyling/COURSE-MernStackFrontToBack

If you want specific code let me know and I'll post it.

Expecting the server to run. Error is;

```
TDI-MacBook-Air:udemy-MERN-FromGithub bob$ nodemon server
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server started on Port 5000
bad auth Authentication failed.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I think that is mongodb error. Can you check if the username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your /config/default.json or /config/production.json there is an object **mongoURI**.

Replace the url with with **user password and username** not your account name and account password that currently functions.

> You have probably deleted that user or changed the password.
>
> Also I tried launching in my local machine and it worked without any trouble.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! absolute life saver - I must have overwritten that code at some point when I was prepping the code for production.

Answer (score 0):

If your username has special characters then change the username with URL encoded format. you will find URL encoding [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)!

I will recommend changing the password to eliminate special chars.

As per the [Mongo DB website](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password):

> ###### Special Characters in Connection String Password
>
> If your password includes special characters, and you are using your password in a connection string URI, encode the special characters.
>
> ###### NOTE
>
> The following characters must be converted using percent-encoding if included in a username or password:
>
> `: / ? # [ ] @`
>
> For example, if your password in plain text is p@ssw0rd'9'!, you need to encode your password as:
>
> `p%40ssw0rd%279%27%21`

The above solution worked for me.